# Arduino - How to convert uint16_t to Hex

Tags: c++, arduino, hex, decimal

I'm currently working on a sketch that will send data to 3 TLC5971 LED drivers. I need to accept a brightness level in the form `uint16_t` and then convert that value into two 8-bit hex numbers to pass to the LED drivers.

Example `65535` --> `0xFF` and `0xFF`

Is there any relatively easy way to do this? I've found several methods that return arrays of characters and whatnot but they don't seem to be easy to implement.

Does anyone have any experience doing anything similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
uint16_t value;
uint8_t msb = (value & 0xFF00U) >> 8U;
uint8_t lsb = (value & 0x00FFU);
```

**Edit 1:**
You could complicate matters and use a structure:

```
struct MSB_LSB
{
  unsigned int MSB : 8;
  unsigned int LSB : 8;
};
uint16_t value = 0x55aa;
uint8_t msb = ((MSB_LSB)(value)).MSB;
uint8_t lsb = ((MSB_LSB)(value)).LSB;
```

BTW, decimal, hexadecimal and octal are examples of *representations*.  The representations are for humans to understand.  The computer internally stores numbers in a representation convenient for the processor.  So when you specify a decimal number, the compiler converts the decimal number into a value better suited for the processor.  We humans, can represent the number in a representation that is easiest for us to understand.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply! I managed to get things working great using your first method. I'm looking forward to better understanding bitmath, I'll start by working through your example! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

```
uint16_t value = 0x1234;    // Use example with different high/low byte values
unsigned char high_byte = value >> 8;   // = 0x12
unsigned char low_byte = value & 0xFF;  // = 0x34
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply, you replied just after an identical answer but thank you for taking the time to help me out!

Answer (score 0):

using a union:

```
typedef union
{
 unsigned short s;
 unsigned char b[2];
} short2bytes_t;

unsigned short value=65535;
unsigned char  MSB, LSB;

short2bytes_t s2b;
s2b.s = value;
MSB=s2b.b[1];
LSB=s2b.b[0];

printf("%d -> 0x%02X 0x%02X\n", value, MSB, LSB);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply, you replied just after another answer but thank you for taking the time to help me out!